# How to pass custom options(--prefix) to configure when rebuilding a 'gcc' package?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, compile, gcc

I want to rebuild the gccXXX packages with a custom `--prefix`.

I know how to rebuild (with the following commands) it, but how do I provide a custom `--prefix`?:

```
apt-get build-dep -y gcc-4.9-multilib
apt-get source -y gcc-4.9-multilib

dpkg-source -x gcc-4.9_4.9.2-0ubuntu1~12.04.dsc
cd gcc-4.9-4.9.2
dpkg-buildpackage -rfakeroot -b
```

Answer (score 0):

The "right" way:

```
apt-get build-dep -y gcc-4.9-multilib
apt-get source -y gcc-4.9-multilib
dpkg-source -x gcc-4.9_4.9.2-0ubuntu1~12.04.dsc
cd gcc-4.9-4.9.2
./contrib/download_prerequisites
mkdir  objdir&& cd objdir
$PWD/../src/configure --prefix=/opt/rdwr_tools/radware-dev-tools-4.9 \
-v --with-pkgversion='Ubuntu/Linaro 4.9.2-0ubuntu1~12.04' \
--program-suffix=-4.9 --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --with-system-zlib \
--libexecdir=/opt/rdwr_tools/radware-dev-tools-4.9/lib --without-included-gettext \
--enable-threads=posix --with-gxx-include-dir=/opt/rdwr_tools/radware-dev-tools-4.9/include/c++/4.9 \
--libdir=/opt/rdwr_tools/radware-dev-tools-4.9/lib --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes \
--enable-gnu-unique-object --enable-plugin --enable-objc-gc --disable-werror \
--with-arch-32=i686 --with-abi=m64 --with-multilib-list=m32,m64 --with-tune=generic \
--enable-checking=release --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-linux-gnu  --with-sysroot=/  --enable-nls


make && make install
```